# Preserving query-string parameters using request scoped beans

Tags: jsf, omnifaces, querystringparameter, viewparams

I have some readonly beans which do not require maintaining their state on postbacks. These beans can thus be request scoped such as,

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Bean extends LazyDataModel<Entity> {

    @Inject
    private Service service;
    private Entity entity; // Getter & setter.

    public Bean() {}

    @Override
    public List<Entity> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        setRowCount(service.rowCount().intValue());
        return service.getList(first, pageSize);
    }
}
```

`Entity` is supplied as a query-string parameter which is defined on the template client as follows.

```
<ui:define name="metaData">
    <f:metadata>
        <o:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.entity}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

The parameter `id` being passed is converted by a custom implicit JSF converter marked by

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Entity.class)
```

---

This bean however, needs to be turned into a view scoped bean only for one reason. There are two global `<p:selectOneMenu>`s on the master page template representing a list of languages and a list of selected PrimeFaces themes.

When either a language or a theme is changed after arriving at the page backed by the above request scoped managed bean, query-string parameter `id` will get lost as obvious unless this bean is designated as a view scoped bean at least.

Changing a language or a theme using a `<p:selectOneMenu>` is only occasionally necessary. Having a view scoped bean only for this functionality should be excluded somehow.

Is there a way to keep this bean a request scoped bean somehow while preserving the query-string parameter, when either a language or a theme is occasionally changed in their respective `<p:selectOneMenu>`s?

---

**Additional :**

Those two `<p:selectOneMenu>` are backed by two respective session scoped beans. Request to change either a language or a theme is triggered by a `<p:remoteCommand>`.

The request at the end, is redirected after a language or a theme whichever happens has been set to the current session as follows.

```
public String themeAction() {
    themeBean.setTheme(Theme.valueOf(theme)); // Theme is an enum. theme is a request parameter which is supplied by a <p:remoteCommand>.
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
}
```

The current bean is a request scoped bean and the `ThemeBean` is a session scoped bean which has been injected into the current request scoped bean.

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14735726

Comment: That works but it happens with `<f:viewParam>` only. Why doesn't it happen with `<o:viewParam>`?

Comment: That's unexpected. I will check it. You can in your specific case also just use `<o:form useRequestURI="true">`.

Comment: `<o:form useRequestURI="true">` works with `<f:viewParam>` but has no effect, when `<o:viewParam>` is used as happens with `<o:form includeViewParams="true">`.

Comment: I forgot myself that `<o:viewParam>` is stateless and doesn't run on postbacks and should be used with view scoped beans only. Perhaps I should clarify that more in its javadoc. Is there a technical reason you're using it instead of `<f:viewParam>`?

Comment: The reason for using `<o:viewParam>` is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23906643/1391249) but this can be avoided in this specific case. Thus, I can safely go with `<f:viewParam>` in this case, since the bean is readonly and no Ajaxical postbacks to this bean are made.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `<f:viewParam>` should be all fine in this specific case with a request scoped bean.

Comment: What is the difference between `includeRequestParams` and `includeViewParams` in `<o:form>`? Can't understand just by reading the documentation, "*Whether to include all URL (GET) request parameters in the action URI. This overrides `includeViewParams`.*"

Comment: `includeQueryString` was after all perhaps more clear. All of those GET request parameters which you see in browser's address bar thus.